# displaying fields

Tags: php

I have this code

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("juliver", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu");

$sm = "";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

$sm .= "<li><a href='#".$row['page'].'">'.$row['menulist']."</a></li>";

}

mysql_close($con);

?>
<? echo $sm; ?>
```

My database is look like this.

```
id    menulist          page
1     Home              tb1
2     Gallery           tb2
3     Clothing          tb3
4     Furniture         tb4
5     Household-items   tb5
```

the output should be this if converted into html.

```
<li><a href="#tb1">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#tb2">Gallery</a></li>
<li><a href="#tb3">Clothing</a></li>
<li><a href="#tb4">Furniture</a></li>
<li><a href="#tb5">Household-items</a></li>
```

I tried removing, adding, renaming and etc into the code and etc. but im still stuck and none of them work.

please help me.

Comment: you forgot a semicolon at the end of the line inside the bucle

Comment: Off topic, but you should really escape the values coming from your db, and when writing strings with PHP variables inside I find it easier to do this: $sm = "<li><a href=\"#{$row['page']}\">{$row['menulist']}</a></li>";

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the ending `;`

```
$sm = "<li><a href='#".$row['page']."'>".$row['menulist']."</a></li>"; //<<----there
```

You might want to look into finding an editor that does syntax highlighting, as this would have been an easy one for it to have shown you.

Answer (score 1):

You missed a semicolon @ this line

```
$sm = "<li><a href='#".$row['page']."'>".$row['menulist']."</a></li>"
```

Change to

```
$sm = "<li><a href='#".$row['page']."'>".$row['menulist']."</a></li>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to append the HTML rather than overwrite the value each time?

```
$sm = "<li><a href='#"...
```

Should this be:

```
$sm .= "<li><a href='#"
```

**EDIT:**

Here is how I would structure the page (just my preference):

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("juliver", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu");

mysql_close($con);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo "<li><a href='";
  echo $row['page'];
  echo "'>";
  echo $row['menulist'];
  echo "</a></li>\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: Yes, I want to append, I want to loop the records till the end of it.

I have 3 records in my database, 1st is 'id', 2nd is 'menulist' and the 3rd is 'page'

id menulist          page
1  Home              tb1
2  Gallery           tb2
3  Clothing          tb3
4  Furniture         tb4
5  Household-items   tb5

then the output should be this if converted into html.

<li><a href="#tb1">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#tb2">Gallery</a></li>
<li><a href="#tb3">Clothing</a></li>
<li><a href="#tb4">Furniture</a></li>
<li><a href="#tb5">Household-items</a></li>